# Factorization of non-stationary states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

It is common to read about two particles systems in which the particles are independent and their wave function is factorized as $\psi(x_a) \psi(x_b)$ where $\psi(x_a)$ and $\psi(x_b)$ are stationary states (eigenfunctions of the hamiltonian).

However, i'm wondering if it is possible to have factorized non-stationary states and if, in this case, the meaning of the factorization remain the same.

**example**:
Consider a system made by two distiguishable particles that is changing in time. At $t=0$ the particles are far apart while at $t>>0$ the particle are close each other.
At $t=0$ since the particles are far apart they can be considered independent. For this reason the probability to find a particle in a certain position should not be influenced by the probability of the other one to be somewhere else.
So at $t=0$ the wave function should be written as $\Psi_{t=0}(x_a)\Psi_{t=0} ^{'}(x_b)$ where neither $\Psi_0(x_a)$ nor $\Psi_0^{'}(x_b)$ are stationary states.

Comment: If the total Hamiltonian $H$ is $H=H_1+H_2$, where $H_i$ acts only on the coordinates $x_i$ of the particle $i=1,2$, then the answer is yes: you start with a "factorized" state at $t=0$ and this will remain true also at any $t>0$.

Comment: i agree but that is not the question. The question is if i factorize a non stationary state at a certain time (like the one in the example) the meaning in the same as in the stationary states (namely, independency)

Comment: The answer is yes, of course.. why should this interpretation change with time? :)